FFmpeg lavfutils.h seems to be missing
The lavfutils.h file is missing from the include folder where the ffmpeg library was put.
I installed the ffmpeg library to load an image in c++. I installed it using ./vcpkg ffmpeg. The ff_load_image function is in lavfutils.h, but that file is missing from the ffmpeg_x64-windows folder where vcpkg put the rest of the library.
Has the way you load images changed? Or have I installed ffmpeg incorrectly?

lavfutils.h is not a public header. A ffmpeg function starting with ff is not a public function. It is only for internal use, and is in fact, used only by 4 filters.
